# Open sets and images of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ and that $M\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ is open, need $f(M)$ be open as well? I am aware that for general metric spaces, this needs not to be the case but if we restrict to the two metric spaces mentioned above, does the result hold?

Thanks!

Comment: No, if $f$ is a constant function then $f(M)$ is not open for any nonempty subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac1{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+\cdots+{x_2}^2+1}$ and $M=\mathbb R^n$. Then $f(M)=(0,1]$, which is not open.

Answer (score 0):

This is already false for $n = 1$. Let $M = (-1, 1)$ and $f(x) = x^2$. Then $f(M) = [0, 1)$, which is not open.

Answer (score 0):

No a continuous function does not have to be open. for example the projections from $R^3$ onto the coordinate axes are continuous but not open.

For example $$f(x,y,z)=(x,0,0)$$  is not an open function because the image of the whole space is the $x_axis$ which is not open.